# createStore is being canclled while trying to import createStore form 'redux'

Tags: javascript, redux

createStore is being cancelled while trying to import from redux.

import {createStore} from 'redux' is not working at all on visual studio code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

`createStore` is shown crossed out because is deprecated.

It's possible to keep using it (no warnings or errors appear) but Redux developers are encouraging the use of Redux Toolkit for writing Redux logic.

> Even for existing applications, we recommend at least switching out `createStore` for `configureStore`

More info:

- https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today
- [Redux createStore() is deprecated - Cannot get state from getState() in Redux action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944111/redux-createstore-is-deprecated-cannot-get-state-from-getstate-in-redux-ac)