# Why redux import is showing crossed?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have started learning redux, but while importing it i am getting createStore as crossed. why it is like that and how to resolve it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vpNJ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redux createStore() is deprecated - Cannot get state from getState() in Redux action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944111/redux-createstore-is-deprecated-cannot-get-state-from-getstate-in-redux-ac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is deprecated and will be removed in future version, but still it can be used.